# read and create pdf sucess but can't open

Tags: pdf

this my code :
this code can read and create a pdf but if open this file i get message "this pdf document might not displayed correctly."

```
URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost/ta/A11.pdf");

        InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        Writer writer = null;
        String inputLine= null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/update/xampp/htdocs/ta/newpdf.pdf"), "utf-8"));
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          // report
        } finally {
           try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and if open in notepad++
C:/update/xampp/htdocs/ta/newpdf.pdf :

```
%PDF-1.4%ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½117 0 obj<</Length 2566
```

C:/update/xampp/htdocs/ta/A11.pdf

```
%PDF-1.4
%ÿÿÿÿ
117 0 obj
<</Length 2566
```

Comment: What language is your code in? It looks like java.

Comment: I think the utf-8 encoding is messing with your raw data (because the pdf data is not encoded but the text inside might be).  This is why the pdf is mostly correct (header is intact, etc) but the bytes that get distorted with the encoding are what is tripping you up.

Comment: thanks for your respone.. I using a wrong code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this the completely wrong way. You can't use `ReadLine` on something like a PDF because a PDF is not a text document, it contains a lot of other data too which will get corrupted by reading and writing it using your method. You need to use a binary method to read and write, for example using `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` directly and not wrapping a reader or writer around it.